# Is there any way to copy files from S3 to redshift through a datapipeline in a predefined order

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-data-pipeline

I am wondering if there is a way to set an order to the way files are loaded into redshift through data pipeline from S3. I know we can use manifest to specify the files but haven't found anything about the order of files being loaded.

for instance, my s3 folder1 has 10 files. In the data pipeline, I set it to this folder, but how can I set an order of these files loading , if we can.

In short as far  I understand there are no means to load files in a predefined order while being consumed by a data pipeline. Anyone correct me if I am wrong.

I am thinking of a case where there can be multiple sources files and they can have duplicate rows but with different values. In such case the order in which the files are consumed is important.

For example , File1 , File2 are part of a data pipeline schedule and if both the files have a common customer entry named xyz . File1 xyz Cost_owed 1000, File2 xyz Cost_owed 500. So in reality the customer xyz owes just 500, but since i use delete and insert mode the order of the files are important here . So my redshift table might end up having an entry for xyz as 1000 OR 500 , in such specific case or any other cases the order of the files matters. Or should this be handled in any other way if so,
 can you give me some ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The order of files doesn't/couldn't matter for COPY command in Redshift since it's a MPP system.

Redshift relies on the SORTKEY of the target table to enforce ordering.

Comment: Basically datapipeline has no means to load data in a predefined order right?

Comment: In a superficial way you're right, but it's very possible to have downstream processes that are dependent on the order of loading. An example might be a column with `default = getdate()`, and then subsequent processes that resolve data depending on that timestamp.